# FreeBSD 10, unable to reach 1 Gbps

Tags: freebsd

I have installed FreeBSD 10-RELEASE and noticed that I'm unable to reach 1 Gbps. To measure bandwidth I use *iperf* version 2.0.5 on both server and host. Results vary every time, but in average we have something like:

```
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   778 MBytes   602 Mbits/sec
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.08 GBytes   923 Mbits/sec
```

I consider result from host to server (923 Mbits/sec) as acceptable while from server to host (602 Mbits/sec) is way below my expectations.
Also, I have the same unimpressive speed transferring files via CIFS to Windows host.

Hardware on server side:

```
Intel Pentium G3420 @ 3.2 Ghz
Asus p9d-x mb
8GB ECC 1600 Mhz RAM
Inbuilt dual Intel I210AT interfaces
```

Hardware on client side:

```
Very-powerful-workstation
Intel Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter (PCI-E)
```

Everything connected into switch that support up to 10 Kb jumbo frame. TP-Link TL-SG1008.

Any ideas how to improve speed between these two?

Comment: Could the `iperf` window size have anything to do with it? http://superuser.com/questions/95546/why-do-i-only-get-300-400-mbit-s-on-my-1000-mbit-s-network/95587#95587

Comment: Have you tried replacing cables and the switch? How about using a cable alone, so it uses MDI-X? What results do you get between the two on-board interfaces on the same system? It's almost certainly not the OS, but you can rule that out by running `iperf` off the [StressLinux](http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/) live CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that's solved, switch is involved someway. Connected two computers via crossover cable and able to get stable 900 Mbit.

Maybe worth to avoid TP-Link's "almost gigabit" switches.